# Vega: Fit canvas to container width

Tags: vega

When I initialise a Vega view, how do I get the width of the canvas to fill the container?  In the spec, I have tried the following:

```
"width" : {"signal" : "width"},
```

OR

```
"width": "container",
```

OR

```
"autosize" : "fit-x",
```