# Responsive width and height - fit entire plot to screen size

Tags: html, resize, responsive, vega

I want to create one Vega visualization with Vega Embed that should fit to screen size, and another one whose height should respond to screen height (with the visualization width independent of screen width). How to do this?

I'm specifying the charts with Vega JSON specifications. Each visualization goes in its own HTML file, on its own Web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the autosize property documented here.

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/specification/

You can specify fit-x, fit-y and fit for your requirements.

**Edit**

Check the signal and autosize properties here to have the chart resize.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAETJBBpRdSRdtgnM2uAA8kCHABs4U7QHc6MbcSQOGcbQ5ITHAOENoQMGyu4toMOBLaCGwMEP6RpIqU0iBIDJhsBgBecGigmACeOCXoAGZ0ALTW2VASmEg04hBoIDhIsrIdZCAAvjLwNGRYaADMAAyzMr39g2gCMrJIbWgA2qDidtUgbUxO2d6+CjugUJvkbIrl3ZrZdsnimGgATAAco9e3ZHuj3QACEXkkGO9VgI-iAbpg7g9ugBhcFvD6oAAs01h8MRwJAABE0ZCMQBOACMuIBQO6AFESVDUN8qVJ-gjAUj0AAxRkYgQ4tlwmlckAAcT5aApZOpHNp6AAEpLmQB2YYAXQ1MgMZH2oSuIH2CEO7lk9GyHTo3RoEG5loRAAoWu92uI4IoAMo0YoOgCU21m6t92gA-GZWq73V6ff7A9pUNpPvNshIDXENgjrbb7XAnRGOlHvbnY0HQ+GXQXPUW-QH1fHE8mZHBSO8uuh3OJZFFUIoFEWRpqhUbDvk2A41Dgzj4-KVRiBU6hdiBm3BW91e1BMKgIak2Blsunbt0MwwECMhSu1+gN1ud3Bkh8ZIfM+hgMMB1qQNAfJdF3sDt01jfqcMgVFU3R6J22RdsgHSlHImwoOgxwgSAdQhLI3R4pyjxzooSDiGQJo0GaMDZEsAyEWgsyULMawgIobyYagmCKH4sLDt05TASU6xsLBGigBmSFHEEqHoQ4zE5BCUJzuIhjVKxfgyPhhGHOMkwfJ+SDWL+S73DQq4YiATBsNg-HZDxgFWbCBlGd0Tg1I+X43Kc6Dca5JSfsgigANZtkuYGHDe2Q1IxZ6oEJiHdChXlNuILTyPBRnuvBTSRS5P7WZ5oWGZJWEirhMimuaGVWegQE5TIkHMayIDAqA5X1VZMgSVJrykue9WfPBTUeVlMjnDOqCzMMc7PtUoB1A4DjwUNhwQAiIQnDOY1jHuqUZdNs0ZfN65wJhY1rWUlQjjYzmrolk3Lu8m2gD4EyCSAe3oFAKWKF1eipA4BZzdOhymeZZ5zttf0XN0ADE0zQyM404Bm13pY1OUVS1X6PT4MVsGOE6UNhtLVQRzE0TCMgNZlbnNVV6O6pjyHY+OKiUB1UIyGwNQ1KkGL1J8c4ItYGKNRjO1HAzuMs1prU0DNADyvRQHQwKBQoxkngg2gALxa9oo6M5Og3-dRsIvVSmpjZqQA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic bar chart example, with value labels shown upon mouse hover.",
  "autosize": {"type": "fit-x", "contains": "padding"},
  "height": 300,
  "padding": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"category": "A", "amount": 28},
        {"category": "B", "amount": 55},
        {"category": "C", "amount": 43},
        {"category": "D", "amount": 91},
        {"category": "E", "amount": 81},
        {"category": "F", "amount": 53},
        {"category": "G", "amount": 19},
        {"category": "H", "amount": 87}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "width",
      "init": "isFinite(containerSize()[0]) ? containerSize()[0] : 200",
      "on": [
        {
          "update": "isFinite(containerSize()[0]) ? containerSize()[0] : 200",
          "events": "window:resize"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "tooltip",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout", "update": "{}"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "amount"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale"},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "yscale"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "category"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "amount"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
        },
        "update": {"fill": {"value": "steelblue"}},
        "hover": {"fill": {"value": "red"}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#333"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "signal": "tooltip.category", "band": 0.5},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "signal": "tooltip.amount", "offset": -2},
          "text": {"signal": "tooltip.amount"},
          "fillOpacity": [
            {"test": "datum === tooltip", "value": 0},
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that already, it doesn't seem to have any effect?

Comment: Could you perhaps give a very short example?

Comment: As far as I understand the docs, autosize makes the plot somehow adjust to the width and height *properties* of the specification. But how do I make those properties responsive?

Comment: Are you using vega or vega lite specs?

Comment: I'm using vega, not vega-lite.

Comment: btw i've partially figured it out: I need to use signals, and set the css width and height of my html elements to 100vh and 100vw. Still haven't figured out how to make it respond to viewport size changes.

Comment: I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: You can compile a responsive Vega-Lite spec to Vega with the editor to see how we implemented responsiveness.

Comment: That is where I copied the code from for the answer. It can be confusing though and ideally, Vega should make it easier to specify or the documents made clearer. e.g. someone else running into the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68481115/vega-fit-canvas-to-container-width